# What permissions do I need to grant a user that wants to run EXPLAIN or EXPLAIN ANALYZE?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I am looking for the permissions needed to grant a user the ability to run EXPLAIN or EXPLAIN ANALYZE.

Comment: The user needs all privileges needed for the query that should be explained

Comment: Good question. I hadn't thought about it in PostgreSQL. Oracle, DB2 seems to require more privileges that just the ones to run the query, but it seems PostgreSQL is more straightforward.